# Access is denied when trying to build/deploy JavaFX Application

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, exe

I am using IntelliJIDEA 14

The error is :

> Error:Java FX Packager: C:\Users\xxx\IdeaProjects\xxx\out\artifacts\xxx (Access is denied)

I can build a normal Jar but when setting project settings to JavaFx Application and Native Bundle as exe I get this access is denied error.

Just re-installed JDK 1.8 and the issue persists. I have read/write access to that drive..